# CSS3 show a division on hover of another element

Tags: html, css

I have the following code to show a  division on hover. It is initially hidden and i'm trying to show one division on hover of another element.

```css
.topNav {
  padding: 1px 15%;
  background: #006cb4;
  color: white;
}
.mainMenu {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.mainMenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.mainMenu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#item1 {
  display: block;
}
#item1:hover #item1detail {
  background: #444;
  visibility: visible;
}
#item1detail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 152px;
  left: 250px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 750px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="topNav">
  <ul class="mainMenu">
    <li><a id="item1" href=""> item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 7</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 8</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 9</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <div id="item1detail">
    Some random content
  </div>
</div>
```

on hover of the list item `item1` i want to show the division `itemdetail`. The above code is not working. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see it the only solution to display the given div without touching the HTML would be Javascript... As the others suggested already...

**BUT...** there's a solution with one slight change to your HTML and CSS each.

The main problem is this CSS-selector:

```
#item1:hover #item1detail
```

which would translate to "id item1detail INSIDE of an hovered id item1".

You can fix this by placing the div inside of the li and change the selector to:

```
#item1:hover + #item1detail
```

Since the div is positioned absolute anyway it doesn't make a visual difference... at least for your snippet...

**Updated version of your snippet:**

```css
.topNav 
{
 padding: 1px 15%;
 background: #006cb4;
 color: white;
 
}
.mainMenu 
{
 list-style-type: none;
}
.mainMenu li 
{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 3px 15px;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.mainMenu li a 
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
#item1
{
 display: block;
}
#item1:hover + #item1detail
{
 background: #444;
 visibility: visible;
 
}
#item1detail
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 152px;
 left: 250px;background: #ccc;
 width: 750px;
 height: 400px;
 border:solid 1px black;
 border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
 visibility: hidden;
 

}
```

```html
<div class="topNav">
    <ul class="mainMenu">
     <li >
       <a id="item1" href=""> item 1</a>
       <div id="item1detail">
         Some random content
       </div>
     </li>
     <li><a href=""> item 3</a></li>
     <li><a href=""> item 4</a></li>
     <li><a href=""> item 5</a></li>
     <li><a href=""> item 6</a></li>
     <li><a href=""> item 7</a></li>
     <li><a href=""> item 8</a></li>
     <li><a href=""> item 9</a></li>
     
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: works now... forgot to add my own solution to the snippet ;)

Comment: Which one is more efficient ? or which one is the better practice ?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to achieve... If it's some kind of cascading menu with sub-menus, etc. The HTML/CSS solution would be better. But your CSS/HTML is very very specific and should and can be more dynamic/less static. How-To: Don't overstress on IDs in your CSS, try to use simple element selectors if possible. Always mind this quote: "As general as possible, as specific as needed" Which can be transferred to almost anything design/coding related: "As few as possible, as much as needed"

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use javascript

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
            if (document.getElementById("item1detail").hidden==false){
                document.getElementById("item1detail").hidden = true;
            }else{
                document.getElementById("item1detail").hidden = false;
            }
        }
</script>
```

and

```
<div class="topNav">
  <ul class="mainMenu">
    <li><a id="item1" onhover="myFunction()" href=""> item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 7</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 8</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> item 9</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <div id="item1detail">
    Some random content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to do it using css using the hover pseudo class.

Comment: Not possible — CSS does not have the ability to traverse up DOM nodes.

Comment: It's absolutely possible to do this with HTML + CSS. Markup is not immutable.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that using jQuery.

```
$('#item1').hover(function(){
  $('#item1detail').show();
}, function(){
  $('#item1detail').hide();
});
```

Comment: OP doesn't need JavaScript for this, just to change their markup.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your CSS isn't working is because you're using this selector:

```
#item1:hover #item1detail
```

Which selects the element with id `#item1detail` occurring within the element with id `#item1`, if the `#item1` element is hovered.

In your current markup, `#item1detail` is *outside* `#item1`, and so does not match the selector. Moving `#item1detail` should get you the behavior you want. (And there will probably be some layout work to do from that point.)

Answer (score 0):

The `#item1detail` element is not a sibling of the `#item1` element, so that is why the `#item1:hover #item1detail` CSS rule does not apply as you expect it to.

I believe if this is to work with CSS only (not JavaScript), then you will have to make `#item1detail` a sibling of `#item1`.